# Using min() result from subquery returns multiple records

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

Hopefully the answer to this question is simple (it seems it should be but I'm missing something)....  I've a simple query that gets the min value from a table (via a sub-query), then using that min value attempts to get a simple months_between final result

The question I'm trying to answer as simply as possible is:  What is the earliest end_date and, how far back from the report_date is this end_date

Here's the query

```
select end_date term_date, months_between (cast (report_date as date), cast (end_date as date)) term_length
from table1
where end_date = 
  (select min (end_date) end_date
    from table1
    where rec_load_date = (select max (rec_load_date) from table1)
      and active_rec = 'Y' and end_date <= report_date);
```

My issue is that while the sub-query works perfectly, i.e, I get a single min (end_date) value back, using it in the main query returns multiple records. (See images)

Current result:
1. term_date = min(table1.end_date)
2. term_length = months_between value comparing table1.report_date and table1.end_date (i.e., the actual end_date values for the records in table1)

Current result (attached image):

Sample of records returned (as many rows as there are applicable end_date values in table1)

Sample data:

```
create table table1 (rec_load_date varchar(25), report_date as varchar (25), end_date as varchar (25));
insert into table1 (rec_load_date, report_date, end_date) values ('2017-08-10', '2017-07-31', '2017-02-28');
insert into table1 (rec_load_date, report_date, end_date) values ('2017-08-10', '2017-07-31', '2017-01-31');
insert into table1 (rec_load_date, report_date, end_date) values ('2017-08-10', '2017-07-31', '2017-04-30');
insert into table1 (rec_load_date, report_date, end_date) values ('2017-08-10', '2017-07-31', '2017-03-31');
insert into table1 (rec_load_date, report_date, end_date) values ('2017-08-10', '2017-07-31', '2017-01-31');
insert into table1 (rec_load_date, report_date, end_date) values ('2017-08-10', '2017-07-31', '2017-04-25');
insert into table1 (rec_load_date, report_date, end_date) values ('2017-08-10', '2017-07-31', '2017-01-31');
```

Any thoughts on how I can get back from the query the following result: '2017-01-31', 6

[Multiple recs returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brOIG.png)

Comment: Well, you have that that records which have an endDate of 20170131, thus those rows are returned. what's the real goal here? What question are you trying to answer with this query.

Comment: hi scsimon, the specific answer i'm trying to get to is this:  What is the earliest end_date and, how far back from the report_date is this end_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you can use this:

```
select
    report_date
    ,datediff(day,report_date,min(end_date)) as DaysBack
from
    table1
group by 
   report_date
```

This will still give you the days back for each row. If you want it for the earliest, or latest `report_date`, then you can add an order by and `TOP 1`

```
select top 1
    report_date
    ,datediff(day,report_date,min(end_date)) as DaysBack
from
    table1
group by 
    report_date
order by
    report_date asc --or desc
```

Comment: tried your query as is and for what you're describing (getting an answer by report_date) it does work, so many THNXS!!!

FYI... I'm looking to get the min (end_date), not the report_date in the result.  But I think you've given me enough to figure out the changes I need to make to get what I want

p.s. Your solution/approach is elegant and simple, I tend to make my solutions more complex than they need to be

Comment: hey scsimon:  i tweaked your query ever so slightly and got the results i needed.  Again your approach was pretty simple and elegant, I need to start thinking this way :).  THNXS!!!!!

Comment: It's easy to over-complicate things @Gar. We all do it and gradually get better at it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your example data is incomplete, but I'll ignore the missing `rec_load_date` for now, and suppose your `SELECT MIN(end_date)` will correctly return one value: `2017-01-31`

But then the outer query effectively searches `select all rows from table1 where end_date = '2017-01-31'` and there are 3 rows (in your sample data, maybe more in your real table) that match this criteria.. So you're getting multiple rows out!

If you want to get just a single row out, you're going to have to nail it down a bit more exclusively. Using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...ORDER BY x)` to number the rows and then selecting the row where rownumber is 1 is one way, even if there are duplicates. Caveat though; you don't have an easy way to guarantee WHICH row gets numbered as 1, if you're doing a naive sort on something like end_date where multiple identical values are present. Either increase the number of columns you order by or pick a different sorting key.

Comment: THNXS for responding and providing a couple insights.  Primarily I spazz'd on the "select all rows from table1 where end_date = '2017-01-31'" nature of what the main query would be doing. Still I'm left with no real answer just yet.Maybe I should re-think the entire approach...?  The question I'm asking is this:  What is the earliest end_date and, how far back from the report_date is this end_date.  NOTE:  All record values have the same report_date of '2017-07-31'